# Got unexpected value in TDS response at offset

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, hibernate, exception, jboss

I am using Java, hibernate, sqlserver 2008 R2, Jboss ,

getting this exception,

```
WARNING [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.internals.TDS.Reader] (pool-26-thread-7) ConnectionID:4 TDS header contained invalid packet length:12590; packet size:8000
2013-05-21 15:59:15,777 SEVERE [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.internals.TDS.Reader] (pool-26-thread-7) ConnectionID:4 got unexpected value in TDS response at offset:7992
2013-05-21 15:59:15,808 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-25-thread-2) Exception in thread "pool-25-thread-2" 
2013-05-21 15:59:15,808 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-25-thread-2) org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC rollback failed
2013-05-21 15:59:15,808 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-25-thread-2)   at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollback(JDBCTransaction.java:204)
2013-05-21 15:59:15,808 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-25-thread-2)   at com.wideplay.warp.persist.hibernate.HibernateLocalTxnInterceptor.rollbackIfNecessary(HibernateLocalTxnInterceptor.java:149)
2013-05-21 15:59:15,808 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-25-thread-2)   at com.wideplay.warp.persist.hibernate.HibernateLocalTxnInterceptor.invoke(HibernateLocalTxnInterceptor.java:72)
2013-05-21 15:59:15,808 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-25-thread-2)   at com.softpak.marserm.engine.library.impl.JobReportStatusUtil.updateReportStatus(Unknown Source)
2013-05-21 15:59:15,808 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-25-thread-2)   at com.softpak.marserm.engine.library.impl.ExecutableJob.run(Unknown Source)
2013-05-21 15:59:15,808 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-25-thread-2)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
2013-05-21 15:59:15,808 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-25-thread-2)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
2013-05-21 15:59:15,808 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-25-thread-2)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2013-05-21 15:59:15,808 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-25-thread-2) Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
2013-05-21 15:59:15,808 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-25-thread-2)   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:170)
2013-05-21 15:59:15,808 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-25-thread-2)   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.checkClosed(SQLServerConnection.java:304)
2013-05-21 15:59:15,808 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-25-thread-2)   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.rollback(SQLServerConnection.java:1655)
2013-05-21 15:59:15,808 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-25-thread-2)   at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.jdbcRollback(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:697)
2013-05-21 15:59:15,808 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-25-thread-2)   at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedConnection.rollback(WrappedConnection.java:500)
2013-05-21 15:59:15,808 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-25-thread-2)   at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollbackAndResetAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:217)
2013-05-21 15:59:15,808 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-25-thread-2)   at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollback(JDBCTransaction.java:196)
2013-05-21 15:59:15,808 ERROR [STDERR] (pool-25-thread-2)   ... 7 more
```

Why is it happening?

Comment: Unfortunately, I got the same error (without the entire Stack Trace btw). I connect (works fine) with SQL 2008 R2 Express, and get the same error when itarating over the resultset.

Comment: Would need to see where you are calling this from. Initially it looks like it is because the connection is dropping for some reason but without seeing more in the question, this may be unanswered for a while.